# How to forecast low values in data more accurately than the higher values?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, count-data

I have a scenario where I have to forecast small values in data more accurately than the higher values. I have data set as below

```
start_time          count

2019-12-14 10:00:00 20
2019-12-14 11:00:00 15      
2019-12-14 12:00:00 3      
2019-12-14 13:00:00 5       
2019-12-14 14:00:00 10
2019-12-14 15:00:00 13      
2019-12-14 16:00:00 7  
2019-12-14 17:00:00 17  
2019-12-14 18:00:00 5 
2019-12-14 19:00:00 4 
2019-12-14 20:00:00 10 
2019-12-14 21:00:00 10
2019-12-14 22:00:00 10
2019-12-14 23:00:00 4
```

I have to forecast low values like 3,4,5 etc... more closely/accurately than other higher values like 10,14,17 etc...

I have tried ARIMA model with all different variations of P,D,Q values. However, I don't get the best match. Over all forecasting performs good but the models fail in predicting lower values or sudden drop in value.

Based on the comments I also tried using PowerTransform from sklearn. Below are my predictions and actual data

```
expected=-0.19118804906910372, predicted=-0.7104364152
expected=0.9532333931783806, predicted=-0.1138364572
expected=0.9532333931783806, predicted=-0.2888092287
expected=-1.4533975814659956, predicted=-0.4581304357
expected=-1.7025204274657684, predicted=0.1207433466
```

After Inverse_Transform

```
expected=6, predicted=4.48549142
expected=9, predicted=6.21553617
expected=9, predicted=5.72463569
expected=2, predicted=5.23741131
expected=1, predicted=6.85605533
```

When I do inverse_transform predicted values are not good with actual values.

What model should I use to solve my problem?

Also, instead of predicting the actual count values, I can convert the count column into a categorical field as below. 0-3 becomes very low, 3-6 becomes low, 6-9 becomes high, 9+ will be very high.

```
start_time          Type

2019-12-14 10:00:00 Very High
2019-12-14 11:00:00 Very High      
2019-12-14 12:00:00 very low      
2019-12-14 13:00:00 low       
2019-12-14 14:00:00 Very High
2019-12-14 15:00:00 Very high     
2019-12-14 16:00:00 high 
2019-12-14 17:00:00 very high  
2019-12-14 18:00:00 low 
2019-12-14 19:00:00 low 
2019-12-14 20:00:00 very high
2019-12-14 21:00:00 very high
2019-12-14 22:00:00 very high
2019-12-14 23:00:00 low
```

What model can be used for forecasting the next categorical values?

Thank you

Comment: just shooting from a hip here, weight them more? log transform? other transform?

Comment: You could log transform them indeed. This would weight much more the smaller values.

Comment: @DavideDN. Could you please point me to some example? I am new to this field

Comment: @DavideDN I have updated my question with my predictions with PowerTransform

Comment: Seems like the problem is more to find the correct model. Data transformation will only allow you to give a different weight to observations, but it will not change the performance of your modeling.

Comment: Given the data that you have ARIMA seems about fine, but I am no expert in the field so I will let someone better suited than me give you an answer :)

Comment: You have count data, so maybe try a poisson time series model?

Comment: 1) Can you think of a loss function that penalizes your model more for an inaccurate lower estimate than for an inaccurate higher estimate? 2) I'd try this: maximum likelihood with a noise model (Poisson, as Kjetil suggests, or something more parametrically complicated) to improve the quantile fit of the negative residuals, largely ignoring positive residuals. Then use the lower bound of the empirical confidence interval. You would need a lot of data (with a lot of negative residuals) to develop a noise model accurately.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. What I realized in time series models or any other models is that when we give the timeseries exogenous variables it would be able to predict accurately. In my case I can give exogenous variables to train and test set. However, I can't provide it for forecasting. In my dataset I can't be sure that at time t this would be the variable, at time t+1 this would be the variable etc...

Comment: @PeterLeopold If I convert the count field into a categorical field like 0-3 becomes very low, 3-6 becomes low, 6-9 becomes high, 9+ becomes very high. What model can I use for forecasting? Could you please point me to an example?